# How PassNGuard Quick Find Pattern works?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm using PassNGuard v1.0.0.0
What does it mean **Quick Find Pattern**? How does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ***Pattern Options***

Built-in pattern matching provides a versatile tool for string comparisons. The pattern-matching features allow you to match each character in string against a specific character, a wildcard character, a character list, or a character range. The following table shows the characters allowed in pattern and what they match.

```
Characters in pattern    Matches in string
----------------------   ------------------------
?                        Any single character
*                        Zero or more characters
#                        Any single digit (0–9)
[ charlist ]             Any single character in charlist
[! charlist ]            Any single character not in charlist
```

## ***Character Lists***

A group of one or more characters (charlist) enclosed in brackets ([ ]) can be used to match any single character in string and can include almost any character code, including digits.

An exclamation point (!) at the beginning of charlist means that a match is made if any character except the characters in charlist is found in string. When used outside brackets, the exclamation point matches itself.

## ***Special Characters***

To match the special characters left bracket ([), question mark (?), number sign (#), and asterisk (*), enclose them in brackets. The right bracket (]) cannot be used within a group to match itself, but it can be used outside a group as an individual character.

The character sequence [] is considered a zero-length string (""). However, it cannot be part of a character list enclosed in brackets.

## ***Character Ranges***

By using a hyphen (–) to separate the lower and upper bounds of the range, charlist can specify a range of characters. For example, [A–Z] results in a match if the corresponding character position in string contains any character within the range A–Z, and [!H–L] results in a match if the corresponding character position contains any character outside the range H–L.

When you specify a range of characters, they must appear in ascending sort order, that is, from lowest to highest. Thus, [A–Z] is a valid pattern, but [Z–A] is not.

## ***Multiple Character Ranges***

To specify multiple ranges for the same character position, put them within the same brackets without delimiters. For example, [A–CX–Z] results in a match if the corresponding character position in string contains any character within either the range A–C or the range X–Z.

## ***Usage of the Hyphen***

A hyphen (–) can appear either at the beginning (after an exclamation point, if any) or at the end of charlist to match itself. In any other location, the hyphen identifies a range of characters delimited by the characters on either side of the hyphen.

***NOTE:*** *Quick Find in PassNGuard v1.0.0.0 is NOT case-sensitive.*